# Django - DateTime Widget format

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

I'm trying to implement a [DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) Widget.

**Widget**

```
class DateTimeWidget(forms.DateTimeInput):
  class Media:
    js = ('js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',)
  def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    if attrs is not None:
      self.attrs = attrs.copy()
    else:
      self.attrs = {'class': 'datetimepicker'}
```

**Form**

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Event
    widgets = {'start_time': DateTimeWidget(),
               'end_time': DateTimeWidget()}
```

**Template**

```
{{ form.media }}
<form action="/event/post" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
</script>
```

The DateTimePicker is well rendered but the format is the default one *%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S*

How can I remove the seconds (to have *%Y-%m-%d %H:%M*) ?

---

**Edit**

I'm trying to get

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" value="2012-04-18 11:01" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" value="2012-04-18 11:01:05" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supply a `format` argument for your `DateTimeInput` instances:

```
class DateTimeWidget(forms.DateTimeInput):
  class Media:
    js = ('js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',)
  def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    if attrs is not None:
      self.attrs = attrs.copy()
    else:
      self.attrs = {'class': 'datetimepicker'}

    if not 'format' in self.attrs:
        self.attrs['format'] = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

This will default to your desired `format` string if no `format` specification is given within the `attrs` dictionary:

```
In [1]: dw = DateTimeWidget()

In [2]: dw.render("foo", "bar")
Out[1]: u'<input value="bar" type="text" class="datetimepicker" \
  name="foo" format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" />'
```

If need be, you can overwrite the format, say with `%Y-%m-%d`:

```
In [3]: dw = DateTimeWidget({'format': "%Y-%m-%d"})

In [4]: dw.render("foo", "bar")
Out[4]: u'<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" format="%Y-%m-%d" />'
```

To manipulate the `value` inside the `.render()` method, you can either use:

```
In [5]: dw = DateTimeWidget()

In [6]: now = datetime.now()

In [7]: dw.render("foo", now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
Out[7]: u'<input value="2012-04-19 17:17" type="text" class="datetimepicker" \
  name="foo" format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" />'
```

Or you can override `render` in `DateTimeWidget` like this:

```
  def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    value = value.strftime(self.attrs['format'])
    return super(forms.DateTimeInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

This would give the following output (without the need to call `.strftime()`):

```
In [8]: dw = DateTimeWidget()

In [9]: dw.render("foo", datetime.now())
Out[9]: u'<input value="2012-04-19 17:27" type="text" class="datetimepicker" \
  name="foo" format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" />'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution for the updated question :)